# css grid shortcodes and wrap in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, grid, shortcode

I'm using a 12 column css grid with the classes .grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .... .grid_12

I'd like to create shortcodes in wordpress.
This is what I did for e.g. a 2 and 10 column style

```
function grid_2( $atts, $content = null ) {
return '<div class="grid_2">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('grid_2', 'grid_2');

function grid_10( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="grid_10">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('grid_10', 'grid_10');
```

The problem is that those shortcodes need to be wrapped in a .row class to make it work

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="grid_2"></div>
   <div class="grid_10"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple solution how to wrap each grid style group into a row class when it's a multiple of 12 (as it's a 12 column grid)

e.g.

```
 <div class="grid_1"></div>
 <div class="grid_11"></div>
```

-> wrap this into a .row div

```
 <div class="grid_3"></div>
 <div class="grid_9"></div>
```

-> wrap this into a .row div, etc.

But maybe there's an even more simple solution to this... ???

I would be thankful for any help and/or advice!

Answer (score 0):

I really like you question. This is how it is usually done in alot of themes that I have seen though.

```
function grid_row( $atts, $content = null ) {
return '<div class="row">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('grid_row', 'grid_row');
```

Then use your shortcode like this:

```
[grid_row]
   [grid_2]Content Here[/grid_2]
   [grid_2]Content Here[/grid_2]
[/grid_row]
```

Output:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="grid_2">Content Here</div>
   <div class="grid_2">Content Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! On the hand hand it makes sense because it also keeps easy to build and the structure is clear, on the other hand the extra shortcode is kind of redundant...

Comment: I know exactly what you mean! If you find an answer the other way, please let me know! I have looked for that before too!