# Trying to create a grid/column shortcode

Tags: css, wordpress, grid, shortcode, 960.gs

I have been going back and forth, doing a lot of trial and error. What i want to output is a grid/column shortcodes.

For example [grid_4]Lorem Ipsum[/grid4]

so far this is what i have came up

```
/*Grid Shortcode*/
function grid_one($content = null) {
    return '<div class="one columns">'.$content.'</div>';
}   

add_shortcode('column_one', 'grid_one' );
```

when try to apply the opening and closing shortcode. My text seems to disappear. I'm using skeleton framework and my CSS for that stylesheet is located in this folder called "CSS".

CSS/Skeleton.css

When i tried to create a clearfix shortcode. It seems to be working fine with no problems and it clears the floated elements. Here is the code.

```
//Clear Shortcode
function clear_fix($content = null) {
    return '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
}

add_shortcode ('clear', 'clear_fix');
```

and my style.css is located in the root and not inside the folder

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a bit confussed by your example as your using [grid_4] as the shortcode but the function in your example would use [column_one] as the shortcode.
If I understand correctly you would also have a different shortcode for every column width? 
You could combine these into one shortcode if you want. 
For example:

```
// column (grid) shortcode
function my_col($params,$content=null){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'no' => ''
    ), $params));
    return '<div class="col grid_'.$no.'">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
}
add_shortcode("col", "my_col");
```

So if you had a 12 column grid this would be used like so:

```
[col no="6"] This is the first column [/col]
[col no="6"] This is the second column [/col]
```

You could also wrap this in a row container for clearing like so:

```
[row]
  [col no="6"] This is the first column [/col]
  [col no="6"] This is the second column [/col]
[/row]
```

The shortcode for the row would be:

```
// row shortcode
function my_row($atts, $content = null){
    return '<div class="row">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
}
add_shortcode("row", "my_row");
```

Lastly I find a have a lot of trouble with WordPress automatically adding paragraph and break tags so I add the following to functions.php

```
// Help clean up automatic paragraph tags
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

Comment: Yes i'm also planning to create different columns width shortcode. Right now I'm just doing some test first. I'll try to understand your solution. PHP is not my forte at the moment. By the way what does the "$no" represent?

Comment: $no is the value of no="6" from the shortcode. So basically the user sets no="whatever" then the column function gives that column a class of grid_whatever. A real example: [col no="3"] content [/col] would output <div class="col grid_3"> content </div>

Comment: Hmmm i tried to edit your code you provided and instead putting in a number i tried inserting <div class="twelve columns">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>'; and it doesn't work. Do i need to use this wp_register_styles in my function.php? I'm using skeleton framework hence the word or class "one columns", "two columns"

Comment: Nevermind looks like i found the solution. I found a user who had a similar problem and a solution or fix was provided and it worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727710/css-grid-shortcodes-and-wrap-in-wordpress

Comment: Now i have another problem. The grid worked but the first paragraph doesn't have any styling but the 2nd and 3rd have styling http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/font_zps75ea6335.png

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: Uhmm no i'm doing it at a local host using XAMPP